# Is there a need to create an object of a class inside the same class?

Tags: java, static, this

```
    package constructorlatest;
    import java.util.*;

     public class ConstructorLatest {

     public static void main(String[] args) {

        A a1=new A();
        a1.calculate();
        a1.display(12);
        ConstructorLatest Cl=new ConstructorLatest(); //1
        Cl.privateMethod(); 
        this.privatemethod(); //2
        this.publicMethod();  //3

    }
     ConstructorLatest C2=new ConstructorLatest(); //4 
     C2.privateMethod();         // 5               

    private void privateMethod()
    {
    System.out.println("this is a private method in main class");
    }

    void publicMethod()
    {
       System.out.println("this is a public method in main class");
    }

        this.privatemethod();
        this.publicMethod();

}



   class A
  {

    void calculate()
    {
      int x,y,sum;
      Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
      x =sc.nextInt(); 
      y =sc.nextInt(); 
      sum=x+y;
      display(sum);

    }

    void display(int sum)
    {   
        System.out.println("no constructor created hence default constructor");        
        System.out.println(sum);
    }

}
```

comment 1 Is there any need to create an object of  the main class (in general).I have heard this() keyword can access all the method of a class,Then why their would be need to create an object of class ConstructorLatest inside the class.

comment 2  since privateMethod and public method are non static we cant access them inside static function.Am i right?

comment 5 why this line is showing error?IMO it is not inside a valid method

Comment: Strictly creating a object that contains another version of itself will lead to an infinite loop. If every cat contains another cat, and I create a cat, then that cat will contain another cat, which will contain another cat, which will contain another cat... Until you run out of memory.

Comment: Doesn't the compiler complain about all of these with explanations why _anyway_? Yes `this` accesses methods _in the same instance_ thence why that `//1` is needed - `2` and `3` won't even compile.

Comment: @Carcigenicate so i should not create an object of the class inside the same class :) Thanks for the explanation . Can u explain the comment 5 why that line doesnt work. i don't understand the warning raised by netbeans.

Comment: @Vld i don't understand the warning raised by netbeans.So i asked here

Comment: @ekaf If your class needs a field with the same type as itself, you need to instantiate the field lazily. Think of it this way: a AI class might contain a "target" field that holds a reference to some other AI object. The other AI object wasn't created *with* the first one, it was just assigned later. And what's the error at 5?

Comment: @ekaf: Of course you can create as many objects of a class within a class. There is absolutely no issue with this. What Carcigenicate meant is having an object that contains iteself, which is a different thing.

Comment: Wait, I actually misread your code. You're trying to access `this` within a static function, which doesn't make any sense. 5 won't work because you're just floating inside a class; that line needs to be in a function.

Comment: thanks :) It really helped :)

Comment: @ekaf Just make sure you're aware of why they're wrong. Understanding how `this` and static methods work is imperative to learn.

Answer (score 1):

The `main` method is static. Therefore you cannot use `this`in it. Static methods can be used without an object, but all non-static methods require one.

The statements with comment 5 does not belong to any method. This is not allowed in Java.